# Is a webmethod in codebehind as secure as the page it is on?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is kind of confusing me.  I would assume the webmethod would follow the same authorization rules set in the web.config as the page it is on.  Will it execute the normal page lifecycle first?  In my case there is extra logic in a basepage that checks further permissions.  Will this logic be executed before the webmetod is called to prevent access from users not permitted to access that page?

Comment: How is the extra logic implemented? What event does it execute on?

Comment: When you say the same rules as the page that it is on, you mean you've got an ASMX and ASPX in the same web application, i.e. under the same web.config? If you're calling out to an ASMX in a different web application it will be different.

Comment: Same web application.  I would just put the webmethod in the codebehind since the ajax calls will only come from the aspx page.  I am aware I would probably be better off using a handler but I don't have full control over this project so I would like to contain the code in the page itself.

Comment: The logic in the base page is checking user roles and other information determining if they are permitted to access the page.  None if this is using ASP.net Authorization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A webmethod must be static and it does not follow the normal ASP.NET lifecycle.

In a webmethod, you can't access the session or the controls on the page.

Since it won't go through all the events, I don't think your PreInit will be called so you won't be able to restrict access through that.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is a web method is much less secure than using the tradition asmx web method. Even though you may have the method hanging of /default.aspx/MyWebMethod, it will not take on any of the built in forms security and can be called from anywhere in your application.